# Breakpoint missed in Visual Studio on second run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have a Visual Studio 2017 extension.
The extension loads code from a database and then runs it in a test-program or separate exe. You can open the classes (compiled into a project and solution) and set breakpoints in them.

The first time the test-program is run, the breakpoint is hit. However, if I don't close the test-program, but simply re-run the test, then it doesn't hit the breakpoint again.

I don't know where to start looking for what could be wrong. The breakpoint doesn't show that it is disabled or unreachable or anything.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program? Maybe it does not hit because the program does not reach the code in the second run.

Comment: @HenrikWilshusen - thanks for the suggestion, but it runs the exact same code. Plus, if you read my post properly you would have seen that if I close the test program after the first run and restart it, it hits the breakpoint, but if I run the test program a second (or third) time without closing it, it doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Comment: There is a known limitation in the debugger engine around loading multiple instances of the same module in an app domain, are you in the same dilemma? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27423/vs-2017-pro-debugger-only-hitting-breakpoint-first.html. If not, could you please share us a simple sample, so that we could reproduce  this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, thank you for the link. I got it solved by setting Debug -> Options -> check "Use Managed Compatibility Mode". Sorry for the long delay in replying.